# If log8n=1/2p, log22n=q, and q-p=4, find n

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I'm having a hard time finding the value of $a$ in this problem. My teacher was trying to explain to me the process in which to get it but I did not understand him.

Comment: Hint: make all the logs have a common base (probably either 4 or 2). Making it $4$ you get $(\log_4(x))^2 = \frac{(\log_4(x))^2}{\log_4(2) \log_4(a)}$. Now what?

Answer (score 0):

**hint**:$$(\log_4x)^2= (\log_42\cdot \log_2x)^2=\dfrac{1}{4}(\log_2x)^2\Rightarrow \log_2x(4\log_ax-\log_2x)=0\Rightarrow \log_2x=0 \text{ or } 4\log_ax=\log_2x$$. The former equation gives: $x = 1$, the latter leads to: $4\log_a2\cdot \log_2x= \log_2x \Rightarrow \log_2x(4\log_a2-1)=0$. Can you continue?

Comment: still confused as to what i'm supposed to do after I get 1/4(log2x)^2

Comment: See edit.I hope you can finish it by now.

Comment: So after I get log2x(4loga2-1)=0 then what do I do? I'm trying to find n